# CodeIgniter Many-to-Many Relationship Management

Tags: codeigniter, many-to-many

Can anyone point out a good many-to-many database tutorial for CodeIgniter.

Just trying to work out the process of creating, and then updating a many-to-many relationship. My example uses a multi-select of values, wondering how you take care of monitoring changes on update etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd like to share what I do in my application. This is basically same with my answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095633/how-to-check-uniqueness-of-many-to-many-collection/2125850#2125850).

1. After user submit, and before entering to database, I will fetch the existing data in the database into an array. Example: `$collection = array('111', '112', '113', '114');` (This is just for example. In real, it should fetch from database then put the value to array)
2. I will check the new user input in two step. First step is to see if it already in the database or not. If it not, then insert. Otherwise ignore:

   ```
   foreach ( $inputs as $input )
   {
     if ( ! in_array($input, $collection) )
     {
       //do insert here
     }
   }
   ```

Then in second loop, I do it in reverse, to delete the data that not selected by user.

```
foreach ( $collection as $data )
{
  if ( ! in_array($data, $inputs) )
  {
    //do delete here
  }
}
```

In your case, you might or might not need the second loop. I needed this since I make the input as checkboxes, that the user can choose to activate / deactivate, thus I translate it as insert and delete.

Since you will implement it using multi-select, then basically it's same with my checkboxes.

If you have structure or code example, feel free to share it, and I will help you fine tune it (of course with my style, that might or might not optimized yet).

Comment: thanks. awesome. i was thinking it might have to be something like this, but was shying away from it. in the end i have gone for a much simpler, delete all associations, reinsert associations. however once i finish the app, i will go back and factor this back in.

Answer (score 0):

This website has some tutorials for many to many. It uses doctrine though.

http://www.phpandstuff.com/articles/category/tutorials

Comment: doctrine is next on my list, but right now i am too new to codeigniter and databases in general to take it to that next level. i.e. want to get my mind round the basics first.

Answer (score 0):

The codeigniter from scratch series will cover almost anything you want to know about the framework

http://net.tutsplus.com/videos/screencasts/codeigniter-from-scratch-day-1/

hope that helps. there are 7 to date btw

Comment: cheers for this, will take a look. i am hoping they cover many-to-many.

Comment: I would recommend to look elsewhere for CodeIgniter tutorials/learning etc. The examples on nettuts aren't the best and Jeffrey Way doesn't seem to grasp the framework quite well enough to be teaching others in my opinion. Instead I would recommend you read: http://www.amazon.com/CodeIgniter-professional-development-Adam-Griffith/dp/1849510903/ref=sr_1_4?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1306688619&sr=8-4