# What's the best way to maintain a many-to-many relationship?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a collection of `tasks` which can be assigned to any number of `users`. I'm using an `assignments` table to maintain the many-to-many relationship:

```
tasks
- id
- title
- description
users
- id
- name
- email
assignments
- user_id
- task_id
```

Each time a task is updated, I handle assignments like this...

```
function update_assignees($task_id, $user_ids)
{
    $this->db->where('task_id', $task_id);
    $this->db->delete('assignments');

    foreach ($user_ids as $new_id)
    {       
        $this->db->insert('assignments', array(
            'task_id'   => $task_id,
            'user_id'   => $new_id
        ));
    }
}
```

It seems like I could search for and update existing `assignments` rows instead of just deleting and re-inserting. On the other hand, it would also take more queries and could therefore be more expensive. Is one better than the other, or am I missing something more fundamental?

Comment: If you have a number of tasks, that can be assigned to any number of users... unless each user can have at most 1 task, you have a many-to-many (m-n) relationship instead of a one-to-many (1-n) relationship.

Comment: @Konerak: thanks, title updated along with first line!

Comment: possible duplicate of [CodeIgniter Many-to-Many Relationship Management](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127286/codeigniter-many-to-many-relationship-management)

Comment: For adding new assignments (when you know you're not deleting any) how about putting a constraint on the assignments table, then doing the inserts and catching any duplicate insert exceptions and ignoring them.  The necessary inserts get through, the dupes get blocked, and you're on your way.

Comment: @Marvo: That makes a whole lot of sense, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest is to just fire up a transaction, delete the old m:n relations, and insert the new ones.

Otherwise you're stuck doing set operations to figure out what's changed, and end up deleting/inserting a bunch of records anyways. Either way you've got at least two queries: delete old records, insert new records. Doing it as a nuke all/rebuild all sequence saves you the calculation overhead, and unless you're dealing with "many" relations, the overhead will be minimal.

Comment: There will never be a high number of relations per task at a given time. It just feels a little dirty to watch `tasks.id` grow so quickly, though I have no proof that it's a bad thing. Thanks, Marc.

Comment: high ID numbers would be be a problem if you're using a too-small integer field. I usually do `bigint unsigned` for all my id fields. A negative ID is definitely weird looking, and the stuff I've built is so unlikely to run into a 64bit overflow that I'd bet I'll win the lotto jackpot before the overflow occurs.

Comment: I just realized that I meant `assignments.id`, and it then dawned on me that I don't even need an `assignments.id` in the first place! It's an 11-digit `int` at the moment, which won't be a problem for some time if that column even continues to exist.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to determine whether any operation is more expensive than another is to test it using a simple, stand-alone application.

Also I would like to at least offer a comment on your relationships and terminology...:

If it is true to say that a single user can only ever be assigned to a single task at a time, then you do indeed have a one-to-many relationship. And if that's the case, you don't need that assignments table unless you plan on storing additional attributes about those assignments (such as date assigned, or assigned by user, etc). Removing the table may better help you visualize what you are trying to accomplish. If you were to remove the assignments table, you would add task_id to the users table.

If a single user can be assigned to multiple tasks, then you have a many-to-many relationship, and that assignments table is needed. If this is the case, I cannot confirm whether it's faster to do updates or deletes/inserts; again my advice would be to just test it.

Comment: Thanks, Kiley. I made the mistake of calling this a one-to-many problem when I should have rightly referred to it as many-to-many. A task can have any number of users, and any given user may have any number of tasks.

Answer (score 2):

At first you should use transaction for this code. Because if something goes wrong you will lose all data. Secondly, you should check and measure two variants.

At first look it's necessary to load data by task_id and insert data only for non-existing users but in this case you should delete query with where clause like in(user_id1, user_id2 and so on). Also if your table is big it will take a lot time to load users_id and maybe more effectively to use your approach with deleting. Anyway try both solution and select the fastest.

Comment: I hadn't considered the potential data loss to be an issue. Thanks, Andrej. If I'm understanding correctly, you're suggesting that I consider the importance of speed vs. safety and test accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Unless performance is a problem you should always use the simplest solution.

Comment: Are you going to post this to every question on Stackoverflow? Because with this wording, you could!